# data is not showing when come back to the previous tab in android

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragmentactivity

In my application, I'm showing 4 tabs using ViewPager.

**tab1** | **tab2** | **tab3** | **tab4**

```
public class Sports_Swipe extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private Sports_SwipeAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBarSherlock mSherlock;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3", "Tab4", "Tab5"};
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sports_swipe);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mAdapter = new Sports_SwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); 
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));

    }
    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                   
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Sports_SwipeAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public Sports_SwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new Tab1();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new Tab2();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new Tab3();
    case 3:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new Tab4();

    case 4:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new Tab5();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 5;
}
}

/////////////////////////////////////
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1, container, false);
     //Here I get all the fields of Tab1 
}
//I did this for remaining tabs also
```

My activity is extends FragmentActivity. Whenever the page loads I'm showing the data of tab1.  Now if user clicks on tab2 I'm getting the data and showing. Now user clicks on tab3 then i'm showing the data of tab3. Up to this it is fine. Now when user goes back to the tab1 then the data is not available on the tab1. It is showing empty page.

How should I save the tab data or tab state.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you just need to set offscreen page limit by using

setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)

Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

so use

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is loaded in fragment at run time (from server) then use `sqlite` to save data. The idea is first you download and save data in database and when fragment change or tab change populate data from database. If you want temporary storage then use load your data in your `MainActivity` and show data to respective fragment.